# Date difference in months with decimal

Tags: sql-server

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, convert(datetime,'01/01/2015',103),convert(datetime,'15/02/2015',103) )
```

I'm getting the result as 1 month only.

I need to get the result as 1.5 months. (means 1 month 15 days).

How can i get the output?

Comment: Surely that's 1.5357142 months as your desired output?

Comment: Fractional months make very little, if any, sense since months have variable lengths.

Comment: What is the result if `start date '31/01/2015', and end date '15/02/2015'`?

Comment: @RowlandShaw according to my answer the correct number would be exactly 1.5

Comment: @t-clausen.dk that depends if you're including partial days, considering the length of the end month/start month/average month length and so many other factors. 15 of 28 days (Feb) would give the fractional part  as 0.5357142, so you've either made the same assumptions as the asker, or you have a fencepost error that happens to match.

Comment: If 2015-01-01 -> 205-02-15 is 1 month, 15 days; is the case 2015-02-01 -> 2015-02-28 1 month, or 28 days?

Comment: @RowlandShaw 2015-01-01 -> 2015-02-15 is 1 month and 14 days. same way as 2015-01-01 -> 2015-01-01 is 0 days

Comment: @t-clausen.dk The question states that period is 1 month 15 days, which is where part days comes into it.

Comment: And also consider how long is the period 2015-01-28 -> 2015-02-28 is: 1 month? 1 month 2 days? 1 month 3 days? something else?

Comment: @RowlandShaw my script has been fixed to handle all dates including the situation you described

Answer (score 9):

Try this, it will calculate the exact percentage of a month "used". It should work on all dates.

```
DECLARE @from date = '2015-01-01'
DECLARE @to   date = '2015-02-15'

SELECT 
  datediff(month, @from, @to) - 1 +
  1-1.0*(day(@from)-1)/ day(dateadd(m, datediff(m,-1, @from), -1))
  + 1.0*(day(@to)-1)/ day(dateadd(m, datediff(m,-1, @to), -1))
```

Result:

```
1.5
```

Note that

```
from date = '2015-03-02'
to   date = '2015-04-02'
```

Will give a result in 1.001075268817 a bit higher than 1 because a smaller percentage of march month has passed before "from" than the percentage of april before "to"

Comment: With `@from='2015-01-01'` and `@to= '2015-12-31' result is `11.96774193548387096` instead of 12.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos exactly what i tried to do. Since it is not an entire year. 1 day is missing. 2015-01-01 to 2015-02-01 is exactly 1 month to take another example

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos according to your logic 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-01 is 1 day, although it is obviously 0 days

Comment: It's a matter of interpretation, i.e. whether `@to` date is *included* in the interval or not. Anyway, your solution can be easily adjusted to cater for any of these scenarios. It's clearly the best answer so far.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos sorry about the late answer. No, you can't defend that argument. With your logic *from 2023-01-25 00:00* and *to 2023-01-24 00:10* would be a positive number although *to* is lower

Answer (score 5):

Use this instead:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, convert(datetime,'01/01/2015',103),
                   convert(datetime,'15/02/2015',103) ) / 30.0
```

`d` is used in place of `month` to get number of days. Then dividing by 30 gives you the desired result.

**Note** that you have to use `30.0` instead of `30` in order to avoid integer division.

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(d, convert(datetime,'01/01/2015',103),
                   convert(datetime,'28/02/2015',103) ) / 30.0 ,

Comment: date difference from month 2015-01-01 to month 2015-03-01 should return 2, not 1.966666

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Yes I know. This is just an approximate solution. It gets a lot more complicated if you want to calculate an exact number. You have to calculate fraction of heading and trailing parts of the interval and add those to the number of months in between.

Answer (score 2):

This will be more correct solution:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(m, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2015', 103),
                 CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/02/2015', 103)) + 
        DATEPART(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/02/2015', 103)) / 30.0
```

To show the difference:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(d, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2015', 103),
                 CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/03/2015', 103)) / 30.0

2.433333
```

and

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(m, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2015', 103),
                 CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/03/2015', 103)) + 
        DATEPART(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/03/2015', 103)) / 30.0

2.500000
```

To be even more exact you can devide not by 30.0 but on the number of days in last month:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(m, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2015', 103),
                 CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/02/2015', 103)) + 
        (DATEPART(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/02/2015', 103))
        / (1.0*DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/02/2015', 103), dateadd(month, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/02/2015', 103)))))


1.53571428571428
```

**EDIT:**

If StartDate is not starting with 1st day, then this version will not work! Then stick to one of other users answer.

Comment: @Jesuraja, yes I have noticed it and edited already 10 minutes before you posted.

Comment: What is the result if `start date '31/01/2015', and end date '15/02/2015'`?

Comment: If you used `datediff(month,...,...)`, it is wrong. You can do only with `day`.

Comment: Yes, I have edited. It will only work if startdate is starting from 1st day.

Answer (score 2):

Improving a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30499818/2622285).

To calculate the number of months it can be divided in three parts. The part of the month from the beginning to the end of the month, the whole months, and the part of the last month.

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '22/01/2015', 103)
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/03/2015', 103)

SELECT  -- Whole months
        DATEDIFF(m, @STARTDATE, @ENDDATE) - 1
        +
        -- Part of the month at beginning  of the period
        (1.0*((DAY(EOMONTH(@STARTDATE))) - DATEPART(DAY, @STARTDATE) + 1)
        / DAY(EOMONTH(@STARTDATE))) -- Number of days in first month
        + 
        -- Part of the month at the end of the period
        (1.0*DATEPART(DAY, @ENDDATE)
        / DAY(EOMONTH(@ENDDATE))) -- Number of days in last month
```

Number of days in a month can be calculate in two ways:

```
 DAY(EOMONTH(@DATE)))
```

OR

```
 (DATEDIFF(day, @DATE, dateadd(month, 1, @DATE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, convert(datetime,'01/01/2015',103),
   convert(datetime,'15/02/2015',103) ) / 30.0
```

ie, you need to get the number of days instead of month from the DATEDIFF and then divide it by 30 to get the desired output.

Comment: It will work if the month has 30 days only,If it is February which has only 28 days,then it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Try below query to Get Month and Days:

```
DECLARE @from date = '2015-01-01'
DECLARE @to   date = '2015-03-2'

DECLARE @castdate date= CAST(CAST(datePart(year,@to) AS nvarchar(100)) + '-' + CAST(datePart(month,@to) AS nvarchar(100)) + '-' + CAST(datePart(day,@from) AS nvarchar(100)) AS DATE);

DECLARE @TotalDays int= datediff(day,@from,@to);
DECLARE @MonthDays int= datediff(day,@from,@castdate);
print cast((datediff(month,@from,@castdate)) as nvarchar(100))+'.'+ convert(nvarchar(150),(@TotalDays-@MonthDays))
```